# UTF-8, XML, and htmlentities with PHP / Mysql

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, html-entities

I have found a lot of varying / inconsistent information across the web on this topic, so I'm hoping someone can help me out with these issues:

I need a function to cleanse a string so that it is safe to insert into a utf-8 mysql db or to write to a utf-8 XML file.  Characters that can't be converted to utf-8 should be removed.

For writing to an XML file, I'm also running into the problem of converting html entities into numeric entities.  The htmlspecialchars() works almost all the time, but I have read that it is not sufficient for properly cleansing all strings, for example one that contains an invalid html entity.

Thanks for your help, Brian

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where the strings were coming from, but if you're getting them from an HTML form submission, see this article:

[Setting the character encoding in form submit for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer)

Long and short, you'll need to explicitly tell the browser what charset you want the form submission in.  If you specify UTF-8, you should never get invalid UTF-8 from a browser.  If you want to protect yourself against ANY type of malicious attack, you'll need to use iconv:

http://www.php.net/iconv

$utf_8_string = iconv($from_charset, $to_charset, $original_string);

If you specify "utf-8" as both $from_charset and $to_charset, iconv() should return an error if $original_string contains invalid UTF-8.

If you're getting your strings from a different source and you know the character encoding, you can still use iconv().  Typical encodings in the US are CP-1252 (Windows) and ISO-8859-1 (everything else.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function cleanse($in) {
    $bad = Array('”', '“', '’', '‘');
    $good = Array('"', '"', '\'', '\'');
    $out = str_replace($bad, $good, $in);
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string from any encoding to UTF-8 with iconv or mbstring:

```
// With the //IGNORE flag, this will ignore invalid characters
iconv('input-encoding', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $the_string);
```

or

```
mb_convert_encoding($the_string, 'UTF-8', 'input-encoding');
```