# How do we decode a string that was posted from other domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, character-encoding

I have created a `<form>` that points to `http://localhost:17099/Form/Subscribe` and hosted in my website...

Every time I try to `post` North European characters, I get them like this:

[image]

That is me posting `Bruno Alexandre å ø æ` as the `Name`.

> **What do I need to do** to get the correct encoded chars?

- I have tried using the `GetBytes()` to figure it out if I could convert from one encoding to the other
- I have tried using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer/1367468#1367468)
- I have tried append `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` to the form

but nothing things to work...

If I check the `Accept-Charset` from the Current Request, I get:

```
ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

If I play around with `System.Text.Encoding` I get this:

```
var name = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(model.Name);
string n = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString( name );
```

`n` will print as `"Bruno Alexandre ? ? ?"`

**Drilling down** and convert the string into bytes, if I send `å æ ø`, this is what I get:

```
var b = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(model.Name);

b[0] = 63
b[1] = 32
b[2] = 63
b[3] = 32
b[4] = 63
```

witch results in `"? ? ?"`

Comment: Probably worth a perusal: http://www.razorvine.net/test/utf8form/

Comment: I used @spender url and got it working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the form is not being posted with the correct content type; it should be:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

You can simple append this to your `<form>`

```
accept-charset="UTF-8" 
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;"
```

so it will end up like:

```
<form method="post" 
      action="http://domain.com/subscribe" 
      accept-charset="UTF-8" 
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;">
```

Comment: appending `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;"` to form generates the exact same problem :-/