# Character Encoding Issue with spring application

Tags: spring, jboss

I am building an application using spring mvc and jpa using jboss7 and mysql in eclipse ide. I am having a strange problem. All my jsp pages are encoded with charset: utf8, which I think is working correctly. But whenever I try to post a data from the jsp to the controller, my data gets encoded with a different encoding style. I tried to look for the header using firebug and was astonished to see that the post request has a header with content-type : "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1". I have already configured the SetCharacterEncodingFilter for UTF-8 in my web.xml (it is the first filter). But still the problem exists.

I also set "org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" to value="UTF-8".But in vain .

Also I have added bean `messageSource` with property defaultEncoding set to "UTF-8".

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" >
```

The problem still exists. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vishal, did you get a solution to this problem? If yes, please post it here so that it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

The *request* header is set by the browser, so your application can't control it. Usually, in your HTML form you could put an `accept-charset=utf-8` attribute to specify the encoding, but that doesn't necessarily work. See this question [Setting the character encoding in form submit for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153527/116509).

Answer (score 0):

you should need to set the encoding of the JVM like follow :

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.io.encoding=UTF-8 -DjavaEncoding=UTF-8
```

thus there wont be any doubt at all.