# Posting Form from UTF8 Page in ISO-8859-1 with MSIE

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, character-encoding

a project I am working on requires me to post a HTML Form which is on an UTF-8 encoded page to a server which only accepts ISO-8859-1 encoding and then show the result in an iFrame. This works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, ... but doesn't work in MSIE (not even 9). IE insist on posting the form in UTF-8. I have no access to the server I am posting to nor am I able to change the charset of the page I am posting from.

The Form contains 2  Elements with constant values but some of these values contain german Umlauts (Ä,Ö and Ü).

So the solution I came up with was to to post the form to a "Proxy-Script" which decodes the request values, posts everything via cURL and returns the result. BUT the server this site is hosted on of course does not support cURL.

So does anyone have an idea how this could be solved? I am at a point where I would use any solution that simply work (even some really weird Javascript solutions).

Greetings,
Jake

Comment: no need for curl, you can use file_get_contents to send a url

Comment: does  file_get_contents() support POST values?

Comment: in this case you can check [this solution](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/09/08/http-post-with-php-without-curl/), but since hosting disabled cUrl, they may disable this too :(, anyway it will be better to test

Comment: Interesting to know... Have you tried recreating the form in a frame or iframe that uses a Latin1 for the page encoding?

Comment: Good idea. But it seems that your solution does not follow a 302 redirect.

Comment: Trying the frame/iFrame solution right now but having trouble getting the result into the right iFrame (which is now in parent -> targetFrame). But the result looks good.

Comment: @Dude Thank you alot! It is working now!!! If you write it in an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the character encoding in form submit for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: I found this question but the document.charset = 'ISO-8859-1' solution a) did not work until page refresh and b) set the wrong charset to the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple hack to this:

Insert a hidden input field in the form with an entity which only occur in the character set the server your posting (or doing a GET) to accepts.

Example: If the form are located on a server serving ISO-8859-1 and the form will post to a server expecting UTF-8 insert something like this in the form:

```
<input name="iehack" type="hidden" value="&#9760;" />
```

IE will then "detect" that the form contains a UTF-8 character and use UFT-8 when you POST or GET. Strange, but it does work.

Comment: I know this hack but this works in the wrong "direction". My form is on an UTF-8 page and needs to be submitted in ISO.