# Multilanguage data load error from JSP page

Tags: java, unicode

I have one stutrs project. In the JSP page user can put any language data like english/japanese/latin etc. I have put `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>` in JSP page so when the user is putting the value in the text box it is showing properly or if the data is coming from database it is showing properly in the page.

But during save the data getting corrupted(I can see it in debug mode as well in the DB). I have put `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in the action layer but still no joy.

How to solve the problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the character encoding in your `<form>` element so the browser knows what your server expects.

This question explains how to do that: [Setting the character encoding in form submit for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But I am failing to identify the right answer among them.

Comment: I have tomact server version 5.5. Has it anything to do with this?

Comment: Just add `accept-charset="..."` to the `form` element and the mentioned workarounds if you use IE. Tomcat has nothing to do with it (except that you shouldn't use such old software unless security is absolutely irrelevant to you).

Comment: I have already put accept-charset="UTF-8" in the form but no joy.

Comment: IE has bugs; that's why you need to read the answers I linked above. They tell you how to set the character encoding of FORM data in IE.