# Checkbox Value - Unrecognized expression in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8 and for some reason, the following snippet of code:

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" id="MOBILE_TECH_1" name="p_v47" value="4G&#x2F;LTE"  ><label for="MOBILE_TECH_1">4G&#x2F;LTE</label>
</td>
```

is giving me this error:

```
Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=4G/LTE]
Line: 4
Char: 13976
Code: 0
```

Comment: something very Microsoftish - don't see it in Mozilla

Comment: Mozilla works fine for me as well but it needs to work in IE8.

Comment: Why would you not just use a forward slash instead of the html entity? That might work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367468/1959948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was only having the issue in IE8 and not in Chrome or Firefox browsers and due to time constraints, I simply performed some backend data modifications to ensure that there were no "/" within the data I was processing.

This solved my issue.