# How do browsers decide which character set to use when sending requests? And how should we deal with it?

Tags: http, encoding, user-agent

**tl;dr:** When the browser/user-agent submits a form, it gets submitted as UTF-8 (in my tests), but does not include that information in the HTTP request. How does the user-agent decide to use UTF-8? And how should the application code (the code which receives the request) decide which character set to use to decode the incoming data?

---

Over the past few days I have been digging around the internet to find out how data is encoded when sent from the browser to the web-server. It turns out the matter is non-trivial as there are no clear standards on this matter.

<strike>[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (HTTP) is largely based on ISO-8859-1 and US-ASCII. But extensions exist to allow for other character sets (like [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)).</strike> **edit:** RFC2616 has been obsoleted by RFC7231 which has removed the note about ISO-8859-1 (see [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-B))

### The Request Body

Essentially, when a user agent sends a request which contains a body, the problem seems to be well defined: Use a `Content-Type` header including a `charset` parameter. For example:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

This is easy to do with JavaScript. But today, I ran into the problem that you cannot specify the charset when using a HTML Form element. In the search, I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer), but in my opinion, the answer is incorrect. It claims to use the `accept-charset` attribute. But from [the reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.2), this header is used to tell the server what charset is acceptable *by the client/user-agent*. Not the other way around.

The related FORM attribute [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) specifies the content-type of the submitted document. But it only allows three values, and if they are not used as-is, the user-agent (Chrome in this case) defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You cannot specify a character set, which is good in my opinion, as it is the job of the UA to encode it for you.

But as a result, the request which arrives on the server is completely devoid of any information about the used character set. So **how shoud the application code decide which encoding to use?**

Another question is: *How* does the user-agent decide which character set to use when submitting a form? In all my tests they submitted it as UTF-8. But where does this come from? Sniffing the network traffic gave me no indication where this might come from. Although, the originating web-page contains a meta-tag saying that the page is in UTF-8. Is that it?

I *assume* that the UA is using the same character set as it just received from the server. But what if the page it requests from application A (in UTF-8) contains a form with a POST action to application B. Assuming that is at all possible (the same-origin policy only applies for XHRIO right?)... In that scenario, the UA no "a-priori" information on the encoding. **How does it decide what encoding to pick?**

### HTTP "preamble" and Headers

*Just noting this down as a reference*

URIs are well-defined after 2005 (see [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), and should use UTF-8. Before that, no standard was defined and it is a bit of guesswork.

Header values are well defined in [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987).

---

References:

- Character Set and Language Encoding for Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Header Field Parameters - [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987)
- Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) **Appendix C** - [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#appendix-C)
- HTML Form Element ([enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype))
- Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax - [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Comment: Please stop worrying about RFC2616; it has been obsoleted a few months ago.

In this particular case it's not an aspect of HTTP anyway -- as indicated in the answer, it's a property of the HTML form submission process.

Comment: Indeed. I have been going over the "obsoleted by" references, but somehow missed rfc7231, which clarifies quite a bit in [section 5.3.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.3). After a day of swimming through RFCs, i must have zoned out at some point :(

Answer (score 2):

The procedure for user agents selecting an encoding for html 5 form submission is described in section [4.10.22.5, Selecting a form submission encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#selecting-a-form-submission-encoding).

It defaults to UTF-8 if no (valid) `accept-charset` element is present on the form.

For [html 4 it is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

> The default value for [the `accept-charset`] attribute is the reserved string "UNKNOWN". User agents may interpret this value as the character encoding that was used to transmit the document containing this FORM element.