# store Hebrew in database with utf- 8 encoding using php and mysql

Tags: html, mysql, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8

I am building a web site with database in Hebrew (using php and mysql).
on general I use chrome to test my job...
today I tried explorer :-0 (yeh... you must be thinking "why the f*** would he do it... ;) ). I found out that all the data that is sent from explorer is stored in ????? and cannot be used.

I use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` on the main page

and `header('Content-Type: text/xml charset=utf-8');`
on the php page that sends the xml files (after he receives get request)

on my connect.ini.php I included the following code:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",mysql_connect($host, $user, $password));
```

my ajax javascript is:

```
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0){
   gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;                                                                                       
   xmlHttp.open("GET","file.php?gender="+gender , true);                                                                                    
   xmlHttp.send(null);
   }else{
        setTimeout('submit_quick_start_form()',1000);   
   }
```

as i said before in chrome everything is fine...

Please help guys...

Comment: can you clarify this ... so User A sends data to your web server in Chrome you receive this data save it to MySQL, User B sends data to your web server in IE you receive this data save it to MySQL, User C goes to your site in Any Browser and you output User A input and User B input and User B input is ????? instead of the correct characters?

Comment: yep only I not output it... I look in  php-my-admin and see the disaster... I guess if I output it chrome wont understand the ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the character encoding in form submit for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: @misha312 have a look at the link I posted, it may have your solution (IE Hack)

Comment: @misha312 how are you submitting the form data? ajax? or is it a straight post?

Comment: I am using ajax (with method get)... ok I found something... whem i delete the charset=utf-8 from the main page my whole page is in unreadable language but the input to the database is good (normal Hebrew)  its like some double conversion issue

Comment: By the wey I tried the hack and it didnt work

Comment: please update your question with your `js` ajax submit code

Comment: Where is comment about `mysql_` functions ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
(click for full size)
Shown in the first 3 GETs, in order, I found that Chrome, Firefox, and IE all produce different results.  But I guess theoretically, Firefox does it right.  In any case, they all give the same result (next 3 GETs in order), if we encodeURIComponent() the input.value.  Like such:
xhr.open('GET', location.href+"?"+**encodeURIComponent**(test.value), true)
......
<input type=text id=test name=test value="שלום מישה">

Comment: So let me understand I need to insert encodeuricomponent to my javascript in order to solve this problem??