# Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC app: return response in non-utf8 character encoding

Tags: utf-8, asp.net-core, character-encoding

I did the following:

1. Installed System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.4.0
2. In Startup.ConfigureServices() I have:

   ```
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
   ```
3. In CustomersController

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
   {
       ...

       return View();
   }
   ```
4. Register.cshtml content like below:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = null;
   }
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=shift_jis" />
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
       <FORM action="https://some_external_web_app" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="@ViewBag.CustomerId" />
           <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="@ViewBag.CustomerName" />
           ...
           <input type="submit" value="Start Registration" />
       </FORM>
   </BODY>
   </HTML>
   ```

Note that, view has meta tag with charset="shift_jis" (Japanase, code page 932) encoding.
The form will be posted to some external web app. That app refuses to accept posting because of incorrect character encoding. What should I do? I saved Register.cshtml in shift_jis encoding (VS2017 File, Save As, Save with Encoding, and selected shift_jis); didn't work.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/153527/2698119